# How can I get OpenJRe working on my machine?

Tags: java

I have installed OpenJRE Version 8 on my machine. When I say installed I mean I extracted the files from the zip and copied them to my test machine. I then set the PATH and JAVA_HOME variables to point to this new location. However none of the applications that previously ran with the regular Oracle Java will run with this Open version. Any ideas as to what I can do to fix this issue is appreciated. My work has tasked me with this and I'm just not that familiar with all the ins and outs of Java. Thanks!

Comment: The error I receive is: "Windows has blocked this software because it can't verify the publisher". I believe this is because it doesn't recognize Java as being installed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Again, welcome to the community!